# Openntf Domino API v10 "Completed a formula" added to logs

Tags: xpages

Since the installation of Openntf Domino API V10 I am receiving lots of logging messages.

HTTP JVM: Evaluating a formula: " "
HTTP JVM: Completed a formula in 0ms: " "

Does anyone know if this is related or just a coincidence. There is nothing in my developments to produce this string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've just been notified of it on Slack, along with the commit that added this. A debug variable was inadvertently left at `true`. Please look for an updated release shortly.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response Paul

Comment: Paul, would you know if the sudden appearances of com.ibm.xsp.acl.NoAccessSignal exception errors when accessing our site would be related to this or the move to V10, there have been no changes in my design.

Comment: Mark, NoAccessSignal has been around in 9.0.1 too.

Comment: I use a catch to skip error handling if it's a 302. As Per says, it's been around for a while

Comment: Strange, I must have only just noticed it. Thanks for your help lads.

Comment: For info, updated releases have been posted to OpenNTF.

Comment: I don't see anything newer than 15/10/18 on OpenNTF Paul, ie. it doesn't appear to be a new release?

Comment: The updated release has been posted https://oda.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/OpenNTF%20Domino%20API/releases/7CC561B369EA5FAB852583770035BFA4. Just the ODA files themselves can be downloaded from http://p2.openntf.org/repository.nsf/home.xsp/oda/release. In DDE you can install directly from there - instead of downloading and adding a folder location, use "Add Remote Location" in the File > Application > Install... setting and point to "http://p2.openntf.org/repository.nsf/home.xsp/oda/release"

Comment: Thanks Paul works a treat, well it did after I had sussed out I need to Sign all Content in the Update site.